# CSS: Why is my box size increasing with padding when in box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css, border-box

Studying coding at the moment and am building a simple rock, paper scissors game. I have set `box-sizing: border-box` assuming this would stop the box size from growing when padding is added. However my box grows when i add padding and I am not sure why? I would expect this with `content-box` only. Could somebody please help? Thank you. Code below:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.score-board {
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 46px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

.badge {
    background: #e2584D;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

#user-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -25px;
}

#computer-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: -30px;
}

<div class="score-board">
    <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
    <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
    <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show enough code to reproduce the problem? Does it grow both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: It only grows vertically. I will try and edit the above to add more code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your "score-board" is an inline element (a span, label...), or it was made inline by another CSS rule, and inside it there are elements which overflow it. You can see a full example bellow.

To solve this, try adding `display:  block` or `display: inline-block` to the `score-board` css rule. Also, add `overflow: hidden` so if the content is too big to fit, the overflow part wont be visible (or better, change yout content so it fits the scoreboard).

Edit:
Something else I changed in the example: For testing, I added a border and background color, an also a background clipping, this way you can see what space is actually been taken for border and padding witout altering the layout/sizes.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.score-board {
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 3px solid orange; /* -> test */
    background-color: blue; /* -> test */
    background-clip: content-box; /* -> test */
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 46px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="score-board">Long content here</span>
<div class="score-board">Long content here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. There is a span in the score board. I just realised it's only vertical padding that affects the box size. Does that mean something? :


    `<div class="score-board">
        <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
        <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
        <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
    </div>`